# How to count a specific length of a list in flutter

Tags: list, flutter, dart, filter

I created a task list. I want to count the tasks length like this:

`ongoing tasks` = `task list length` - `isDone tasks`

I want to find the `isDone` tasks count in this case. As to the picture `isDone` tasks = 2.

[image: sample image]

These are the classes that I created.

```
class Task {
  final String taskName;
  bool isDone;

  Task({required this.taskName, this.isDone = false});

  void toggleDone() {
    isDone = !isDone;
  }
}
```

........

```
class Taskdata with ChangeNotifier {
  final List<Task> _tasks = [];

  UnmodifiableListView<Task> get tasks {
    return UnmodifiableListView(_tasks);
  }

  int get tasksCount {
    return _tasks.length;
  } 
  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [where](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/where.html) function to filter a list per a certain condition:

```
 int get tasksCount {
    List<Task> tasksLeft = _tasks.where((task) => !task.isDone).toList();  //where returns an iterable so we convert it back to a list
    return tasksLeft.length;  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

if something goes wrong, you may need to convert `List` to `Iterable`

```
int get doneCount {
    Iterable<Task> tasksDone = _tasks
        .where((task) => task.isDone)
        .toList(); //where returns an iterable so we convert it back to a list
    return tasksDone.length;
  }
```

Comment: Leaving the fact that you just copy-pasted my answer, you have an error in your code. Since you are converting the result of the where clause to a list, it's type cannot be an Iterable.

Comment: I copied your code and pasted and it gave me an error. Vs code suggested me to change list to iterable. And it worked. To your comment the answer is simply a big yes

Comment: If you would have looked at the code more closely, you could have observed there was an extra closing parenthesis... Removing it solved the error. And simply copy-pasting another person's solution is a form of [plagiarism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism#:~:text=Plagiarism%20is%20the%20representation%20of,a%20breach%20of%20journalistic%20ethics.).

Comment: I saw the extra parenthesis. But it was not the error I got. If you do mind plagiarism in a platform like this, it does not make any sense.

Comment: Plagiarism is absolutely forbidden here.  We require answers that copy content from elsewhere to cite their sources: [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

Comment: To avoid plagiarism, I tried to rewrite the code in my own words and flutter framework didn't like that much. So I'll make sure to give the attribution as a comment within my app source code